# Authors Ability to Review Post from Contributors

Tags: user-roles, author

I am developing a CMS using WordPress. I have different user roles. I have different departments and I want users (Role of contributors) to post items that would be submitted for review by Users (authors and administrators). My challenge is that the Role "authors" is not seeing the post submitted by the contributors only admin. What do I do to give the Author rights to view this post and can review them and publish them.

Can I get a plugin that can do this?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq].

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your authors need to be 'Editors'.

Comment: Please elaborate why this should be the solution.

Comment: Old post, but for the record.  Editors review posts made by contributors, so that they can then publish them.

Comment: Please add additional info as [edit], not as comment.